# Feed dialog doesn't publish large images

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to post to User's Wall large images through FB.ui 'feed' but the post only show a small image in the left side as usual. When I use the sharer.php, the image looks large. What I need to define to post large images using the Share dialog.

```
FB.ui({
  app_id:       '<%= ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'] %>',
  method:       'feed',
  link:         '<%= request.original_url %>',
  name:         'A name example',
  redirect_uri: '<%= ENV['HOST'] %>',
  caption:      'An example caption',
  description:  'An example description',
  picture:       '<%= ENV['HOST'] %><%= asset_path "Facebook/#{params[:page]}.jpg" %>'
}, function(response){});
```

I have defined an og:image, og:type, etc but now way. Share dialog only post small images.

The image are 1200x603. The only warning the debugger is returning me is about og:url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I exactly use:

```
 FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: '<url that I would like to share>',
        name: "Js name",
        picture: 'http://<domain>.com/media/images/questionnaire/1/1.jpg',
        caption: 'Js caption',
        description: 'Js description'

    }, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
```

and this is what I see:
[image]

There is no `og` tags in my link address's html. Be careful about using `link` attribute instead of `href` attribute. I spent lots of hours just for finding that I should use `link` attribute instead of `href` attribute.