# Facebook share: only a SMALL image shows on the web (LARGE in iOS app)

Tags: ios7, facebook-sdk-3.1, fbdialogs

Using `presentShareDialogWithLink` or `Open Graph` or something else, **(how) can one post a *large* thumbnail on the web without a login-session** (i.e. with a fast-app-switch)? Namely, the official-snippet doesn't present a *large* thumbnail on the web (as seen further below).

```
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"]
                                 name:@"name"
                              caption:nil
                          description:@"description"
                              picture:[NSURL URLWithString:linkToAnImage]
                          clientState:nil
                              handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) 
                                      {}];
```

As seen below, the snippet *does* present the large thumbnail in iOS app, but **the *same* share is on the web visible only as the old/small thumbnail** on the left side. The image is of 2048 x 1072 resolution.

- web

[image]

- iPhone

[image]

- iPad

[image]

Somewhat related question: [Feed dialog doesn't publish large images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817625/feed-dialog-doesnt-publish-large-images)

### Another try with Open Graph

Under `Facebook > Apps > Open Graph >` I've created **(1)** `share` under `> Action Types` and **(2)** `link` under `> Object Types`. Then, using the snippet below, I do get the fast-switch-to-Facebook-iOS-app, but the **share dialog disappears quickly and the top-right `Post` button is disabled** (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552944/facebook-share-dialog-on-ios-publish-button-always-greyed-out)). Facebook dashboard still shows **(1)** `share` action-type with a blue mark for `Unapproved` status, if that makes a difference when testing.

```
id object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:link", FBAppNamespace]
                                                    title:@"name"
                                                    image:@"http://link.com/to/an/image.jpg"
                                                      url:@"http://appstore.com/keynote"
                                              description:@"description"];

id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
action[@"link"] = object;
FBOpenGraphActionShareDialogParams* params = [FBOpenGraphActionShareDialogParams new];
params.action = action;
params.actionType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:share", FBAppNamespace];
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:params.action
                                          actionType:params.actionType
                                 previewPropertyName:@"link"
                                             handler:nil];
```

Comment: Have you gone through the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/#photos  Adding photos to stories to column?

Comment: @Harsh, no since mine aren't `user_generated`, but I did try Open Graph again (see the updated question). Sadly, after the fast-switch to iOS-Facebook, the shared dialog disappears (after a second or so), [as for this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552944/facebook-share-dialog-on-ios-publish-button-always-greyed-out).

Comment: Well, it seems it works at least with the `FBWebDialogs` as a backup.

Comment: Have you implemented the correct OpenGraph tags as stated here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#tags and have you run your it through the Opengraph Debugger?

Comment: @Tobi, how should I implement OG tags (e.g. `og:image`) in above, self-contained snippet? Or are these tags for use in web SDK, since the section you linked to starts with `"Open Graph tags are included in your page’s HTML ..."`?